# Cannot query MongoDB embedded documents using Doctrine2 that reference other documents

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm

Essentially, I am trying to run the following query as it returns the correct results when run at the command line.

```
db.order_in_progress.find({ "orderProducts.carrierAccount.$id" : "50db39141311fa9421000000" });
```

I cannot get it to create the correct query using doctine2 though.  My current query is below:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->find($this->getClassName());
$qb->field('orderProducts.carrierAccount.$id')->equals(new \MongoId($carrierAccount->getId()));
return $qb->getQuery()->execute();
```

Which is resulting in the following query being run.

```
db.order_in_progress.find({ "orderProducts.carrierAccount": ObjectId("50db39141311fa9421000000") })
```

If I remove the \MongoID stuff, I end up with the following query instead.  This is closer, but it is truncating the "$id" part off the field name.

```
db.order_in_progress.find({ "orderProducts.carrierAccount": "50db39141311fa9421000000" })
```

The relevant parent document (the document I am querying) looks like below.  (I have stripped non-relevant fields)

```
{
  "_id" : 148,  
  "orderProducts" : [{      
      "carrierAccount" : {
        "$ref" : "carrier_account",
        "$id" : ObjectId("50db39141311fa9421000000"),
        "$db" : "dev"
      },      
    }, {
      "carrierAccount" : {
        "$ref" : "carrier_account",
        "$id" : ObjectId("50db39141311fa9421000000"),
        "$db" : "cerberus_dev"
      }],
}
```

Help!

Comment: Hmm. Well first, are you sure you're using embedded documents and not referencing multiple carrierAccount documents? It looks like you are because the point of embedding documents is to not store any references for faster read. Not quite sure why it's not letting you use $id inside your querybuilder though. However, if you are using references and want a quick fix and some optimization as well, you can make orderProducts reference carrierAccounts simply. By using @ODM\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="CarrierAccount", simple=true)

Comment: I am embedding the orderproduct object 1+ times in the order document.  An orderproduct can have a single reference to a carrier account.